# How to extract data using Text.JSON?

Tags: json, haskell, io

I'm trying to write a wrapper around `ffprobe` that extracts `value` in JSON of the format `{"format": {"format_name": value}}`. The JSON is output by a created process. Here's what I've gotten to.

```
import System.Process
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Text.JSON

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    (_, Just out, _, p) <- createProcess
        (proc "ffprobe" [args!!0, "-of", "json", "-show_format"])
        { std_out = CreatePipe }
    s <- hGetContents out
    --putStrLn $ show (decode s :: Result JSValue)
    --waitForProcess p
    --putStrLn $ valFromObj "format_name" format
    --    where format = valFromObj "format" rootObj
    --          (Ok rootObj) = decode s :: Result (JSObject (JSValue))
    let (Ok rootObj) = decode s :: Result (JSObject (JSValue))
    let (Ok format) = valFromObj "format" rootObj :: Result (JSObject (JSValue))
    putStrLn format_name
        where (Ok format_name) = valFromObj "format_name" format
```

It fails to compile with:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ffprobe.hs, ffprobe.o )

ffprobe.hs:20:59: error:
    Variable not in scope: format :: JSObject JSValue
```

I'm confused about several things, including why I can't get the last line to compile:

1. Why can't I assert for `Ok` in the `Result` after the `::`. Like `:: Result Ok JSObject JSValue`?
2. Why can't I extract the values in a where clause?
3. Why is it `Result (JSObject (JSValue))` and not `Result JSObject JSValue`?
4. Why is `format` out of scope?

I have a feeling I'm mixing the IO and Result monads together in the same `do` block or something. Is `Result` even a monad? Can I extract the value I want in a separate `do` without crapping all over the `IO` `do`?

Comment: On the off-chance you just want to decode JSON, you know there is a popular Haskell library for that called [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your compile error is because of the position of the `where`. Try

```
main = do
    ...
    let (Ok format) = valFromObj "format" rootObj :: Result (JSObject (JSValue))
    let (Ok format_name) = valFromObj "format_name" format
    putStrLn format_name
```

The scope of the `where` is outside the `do` so it isn't aware of `format`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

```
main = do
  let bar = "only visible inside main? "
  return baz
  where
    baz = bar ++ " yes, this will break!"
```

This gives:

```
test.hs:7:11:
    Not in scope: ‘bar’
    Perhaps you meant ‘baz’ (line 7)
```

Let bindings unlike function arguments are not available in where bindings. Above `bar` is not in scope for `baz` to use it. Compare to your code.